# How to implement a JavaScript search filter function in a table

Tags: javascript, html, css, filter, html-table

I am attempting to assemble a search/filter function in JavaScript for an HTML table. The example given in W3Schools allows the user to input the item in the first cell of a given row, thus revealing the targeted cell and the entire row associated with that cell, while filtering out all other rows. In my example below, inputting "Germany" filters out everything but "Germany, Austria, Belarus, Hungary". However, I want to expand the filtering function to target specific cells. If I input a 2nd column cell such as "Austria", then I would want the function to filter out all other rows and cells, except for the "Austria" cell. How should I configure the table and function to do this?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h2>Countries</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for countries..">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
    <td>Belarus</td>
    <td>Hungary</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>France</td>
    <td>Morocco</td>
    <td>Mali</td>
    <td>South Africa</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Russia</td>
    <td>Belgium</td>
    <td>Tanzania</td>
    <td>Brunei</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Argentina</td>
    <td>Ireland</td>
    <td>Ghana</td>
    <td>Indonesia</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, however, you should also consider [adding a `debounce()` function](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-in-javascript-improve-your-applications-performance-5b01855e086).

```
const myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
const table = document.getElementById('myTable');
const cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');
const cellArr = [...cells];

myFunction = (val) => {
 cellArr.forEach(c => {
        c.style.display = 'none';

        if (c.innerText.toLowerCase() === val.toLowerCase()) {
            c.style.display = 'table-cell';
        }
    })
};
```

You also need to pass the value in in your html:

```
<input type="text" 
       id="myInput" 
       onkeyup="myFunction(this.value)" 
       placeholder="Search for countries..">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var input = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
    for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
        var that = tds[i];
        if (that.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(input.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
            that.style.display = 'table-cell';
        } else {
            that.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

You can iterate over the DOM-Elements directly. I hope this solution is understandable. I tried to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Just a friendly reminder: `var` is generally considered bad practice now, especially within a `for` loop. `let` is preferred. https://wesbos.com/for-of-es6/ since it is block-scoped.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code to get the value of the input on each entry, and iterate on the table while checking the value of the first column of each row. I don't know what are you exactly tried to do behind this.

```
var element = document.getElementById('myInput');

element.addEventListener("keyup", function (evt){
  var currentInputValue = this.value;
  var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
  var trs = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for(let i = 0; i < trs.length; i++){
    //I just print value but add the wanted test like levenshtein algorithm to match with the closer value or whatever
    alert(trs[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerText + " " + currentInputValue);
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: Just a friendly reminder: `var` is generally considered bad practice now, especially within a `for` loop. `let` is preferred. https://wesbos.com/for-of-es6/ since it is block-scoped.